# How do we retrieve PlaceID if I have place coordinate info on IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I am using GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces APIs. I am trying to retrieve place details when I tap a marker. I understand I can retrieve place detail by using a `placeID`, but how do I retrieve a `PlaceID` in the first place? I have the coordinates of the place.

There is information on how to use a `PlaceID` once we have it, but there isn't much information on how to retrieve a `PlaceID`. I have place coordinate. Either I could use those coordinates directly to get details of the place or use it to get Place ID and then use the PlaceID to retrieve place Details.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `userData` section of the marker.

To define userData,

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let customData = customData(var123: "", var1234: 4, var12345: true)  
        marker.userData = customData

        marker.map = self.mapView
    }
```

To retrieve the information use,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print(marker.title)

         // print marker userData
         print(marker.userData)
         print(CLLocation(latitude: marker.layer.latitude, longitude: marker.layer.longitude))


        return true
    }
```

Finally you can define the `customData` class,

```
class customData{
    var var1: String
    var var2: Int
    var var3: Bool

    init(var123: String, var1234: Int, var12345: Bool) {
        var1 = var123
        var2 = var1234
        var3 = var12345
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but how we can retrieve the `place ID`? I can't figure out how the steps in your answer help solve this problem